# Why is Laravel facade spy not working in certain test cases (Laravel testing)

Tags: php, laravel, testing, cookies, spy

I am studying Laravel's facade spies, but I can't understand why the first test below works and the second doesn't.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit\Helpers;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;

class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function it_sets_a_cookie()
    {
        Cookie::spy();

        Cookie::queue('name', 'value', minutes: 100);

        Cookie::shouldHaveReceived('queue');    // This works
    }

    /** @test */
    public function it_reads_a_cookie()
    {
        Cookie::spy();

        Cookie::get('name');

        Cookie::shouldHaveReceived('get');  // This fails
    }
}
```

[Laravel documentation reference](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#facade-spies)

I'm using Laravel 9.